# Sending keys to background window (not notepad)

Tags: c#

So I've been stuck for about 10 hours now. This code works perfectly for notepad. It sends the keystrokes to notepad in the background without having to click on it or anything. Problem is, no other window or process works and I've no idea why. I tried changing the names and using the window name instead of the process name stuff like that and nothing works. Only Notepad.

No, I can't use SendKeys because I need this to be in the background.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, // handle to destination window
    UInt32 Msg, // message
    Int32 wParam, // first message parameter
    Int32 lParam // second message parameter
);

public void Start()
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    // IntPtr Notepad = FindWindow(null, "");
    //Console.WriteLine(Notepad);
    Process notepadProccess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
    Console.WriteLine(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle);
    Console.WriteLine(notepadProccess.MainWindowTitle);

    IntPtr editx = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);

    PostMessage(editx, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.X, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you give examples of process names which don't work?

Comment: You should be using Microsoft UI Automation rather than sending messages to the pump of another app via p-invoke

Comment: @Lewis42 I tried with BlueStacks emulator which is my main goal. Tried with firefox, send a refresh and nothing. So, I try the .exe name "firefox", the Process name "Firefox" and the window name. Nothing works

If i use FindWindow(null, "Sem título - Bloco de notas"); which will use the window title of notepad, works fine, but if I use the window name of BlueStacks which is BlueStacks, it doesn't work. Same for the .exe

Comment: @MickyD I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried running your process as administrator? Maybe this could help